# Duplicate HTML5 video in iframe on firefox

Tags: html, firefox, youtube, html5-video

I have got really weird problem that occurs only on Mozilla Firefox 40.0.3 (works on Chrome). My system is Ubuntu 15.04.

Youtube video inserted as **iframe** is duplicated, while on Youtube site it is displayed correctly. We have got multiple videos on this page - all inserted the same way - and only few of them are broken.

```
<iframe allowfullscreen="" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/_WVs6AgboiY" frameborder="0" height="315" width="560"></iframe>
```

See: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vujcR.png

I will try re-uploading videos on Youtube.
Anybody have idea what are the reason for this behaviour?